# how can i execute the rest of my program while i execute a file that repeats itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that executes a program I have multiple times, that program I am trying to execute repeats indefinitely unless I force close it, which is how i coded it, but that's not the program i need help with, I need help executing that program multiple times heres the code i have right now:

```
import os
os.system("python3 /Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many\ math\ solvers/space\ heater\ exicuter.py")
os.system("python3 /Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many\ math\ solvers/space\ heater\ exicuter.py")
os.system("python3 /Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many\ math\ solvers/space\ heater\ exicuter.py")
os.system("python3 /Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many\ math\ solvers/space\ heater\ exicuter.py")
os.system("python3 /Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many\ math\ solvers/space\ heater\ exicuter.py")
```

The reason the program that I'm executing is called "space heater" is because its designed to make heat. If you want me to give the code for that other program I can.
CLARIFICATION:
I want this:
[Image of multiple python processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxsOf.png)
and not this:
[image of one python process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T4Xq.png)

Comment: If `exicuter.py` repeats indefinitely, why do you need to call it more than once?

Comment: i want to execute more instances of the program because i've found its most effective when i execute it in multiple terminal instances and so i'm trying to recreate that.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes or use a raw string literal if you want the escaped spaces to be passed through to the shell.

Comment: Use multi-threading to run the `os.system()` loop concurrently with the rest of your program. But why do you need to do this in a single Python script? Why not just run this script in one window, and another program in another window?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't understand a single bit of that sentence, I'm a novice at python, so could you please explain in simpler terms @Barmar?

Comment: This isn't a tutoring service. If you didn't understand, start researching.

Comment: @Barmar instead of messing with threads, they should just ditch `os.system` and use `subprocess.Popen` which will be non-blocking

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then they need some way to periodically check if it has finished so they can start the next one. It won't be easier than threading.

Comment: add some return variables in your script and check the results from `subprocess.popen` to see if one process has been finished

Comment: @Barmar well sure, but that is still the case, and probably harder, with `os.system`.

Comment: `subprocess` is what I would use.  Why use a blocking `os.system` just to then spin up a bunch of heavy python threads when you'd have to deal with managing the threads anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`, that is deprecated and you should use the `subprocess` module. Since you want to open the subprocesses in a non-blocking manner (without waiting for the previous one to terminate) you can use:

```
import subprocess
import sys

args = [sys.executable, "/path/to/exicuter.py"]
procs = [
    subprocess.Popen(args) for _ in range(5)
]
```

I assume you want to start the program some pre-determined amount of times, in the above case, that is 5 times.

You should read the docs to understand how `subprocess.Popen` works if you need any other features (such as retrieving the output). Note, I use `sys.executable` to use the same Python as the one that is running this main file to execute the subprocess python scripts.